# My app Terminates due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase

I am working on an App that has a LoginViewController and a HomeViewController.  I want to go to the HomeViewController only if logged in successfully.  I have read about using the segue programmatically instead of connecting it to the storyboard but I have an issue that I wish you can help me with, I am new to swift.

This code works perfectly, except that when the user enters correct user email and password it crashes and says Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Receiver LoginViewController has no segue with identifier 'testSeg''

I know that I did not define the 'testSeg' yet but I don't know where to do that.  If I connect the segue from the storyboard it goes to the Home page even if the login details are not correct and even if i give it an identifier from the Identity Inspector.  Please help by checking my code of the LoginViewController below

//This is my code for the login, not sure if I should add prepareForSegue or how to solve it

```
import UIKit
import Firebase


class LoginViewController: UIViewController {


    let nextViewController = HomeViewController()

    @IBOutlet weak var loginLbl: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var usernameTxt: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var passTxt: UITextField!
    var pass = true


    @IBAction func userLoginBtn(_ sender: Any) {


        let username = usernameTxt.text!
        let password = passTxt.text!

        if username.isEmpty || password.isEmpty {
            var emptyFieldsError:UIAlertView = UIAlertView(title: "Please try again", message: "Please fill in all the fields we can get you logged in to your account.", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "Try again")
            emptyFieldsError.show()
        }


               Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: username, password: password) { (user, error) in
            if user != nil {
               // self.performSegueWithIdentifier("Klikur", sender: self)
                OperationQueue.main.addOperation {
                    [weak self] in
                    print("ERROR STARTS HERE")
                    print(error)
                    self?.loginLbl.text = "YEAAAAY DID IT"
                  self?.performSegue(withIdentifier: "testSeg", sender: self)


                }

            } else {

                if let errorString = (error! as NSError).userInfo["error"] as? String {
                   // errorMessage = errorString
                    self.loginLbl.text = "error"
                }

                self.loginLbl.text = "Please try again"
            }
        }



        }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }


}
```

I want to define the segue by code and to transit to Home page only if login details are entered correctly.  PS: I am using Firebase Authentication for this and the code is working correctly, just the segue part that causes the crash.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your code is correct. Your storyboard is probably incorrect.  You need to create the segue from the view controller object, not the "login" button, so that it isn't triggered as soon as the user taps the button.

Comment: OMG THANK YOU.  Can't believe it was that easy, I've been trying with it for hours! Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is correct. Your storyboard is probably incorrect. You need to create the segue from the view controller object, not the "login" button, so that it isn't triggered as soon as the user taps the button. –  Credits to: @Paulw11

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct, but probably you forgot create an identifier for you segue, for solve this, you should to create the form the current view controller to the another view controller and provide a name for you this, like this.

[image]

Comment: Hello, thank you for your comment.  I have kept an identifier but It kept moving to the home page once I click the Login button no matter if the username/password is invalid.  The solution was to create the segue from the view controller it self not from the login button as @Paulw11 mentioned.